# iOS UIalertView displaying and processing order

Tags: ios

I have this code

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.gif"];

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    MBProgressHUD *hudSave = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view  animated:YES];
hudSave.labelText = @"Saving...";

    NSLog(@"save");

    UIAlertView *deco;

    if (!isVideo) {
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageView.image, nil, nil , nil);
         deco = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Your photo has been saved." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"oK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }else{

         //UIAlertView *explain;
        //explain = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Wait during processing" message:@"Your video is being filtered, this process may be long, depending of both video and device. Please do not close this app until task is finished." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            UIAlertView *explain;
            explain = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Wait during processing" message:@"Your video is being filtered, this process may be long, depending of both video and device. Please do not close this app until task is finished." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [explain show];

            [self InitialisationRefiltrage:urlVideo];

          //[self InitialisationRefiltrage:urlVideo];
        deco = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Your video has been saved." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     } 

     [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
     [deco show];

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

}
```

The problem part is if my file is a video, it goes directly too "initialisationRefiltrage" (who is working fine) but without displaying the MBProgressHUD and the alert view explain, and after my video traitement, it display everything (explain, deco, and the MBProgressHUD) at the same time.

I try something with dispatch, thread, etc... But i think a don't do it correctly, so can you please give me a clue too how to do that.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code `[self InitialisationRefiltrage:urlVideo]` in the delegate method of your `UIAlertView` so that it is executed only when the alert has been displayed and user has tapped on a button of the alert.

You may also use instead some third-party UIAlertView subclasses that uses completion blocks to make your code only execute when the alert is dismissed. [See my class that does this for example](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAlertView-OHActionSheet).

*Besides, you should respect coding conventions and use a method name beginning with a lowercase letter to make your code more readable.*

Comment: Your subclasses perfectly solve my problem so thank you very much. Now both my alert and progress bar are working smoothly and with rhythm. I also modify the name of the function, normally i respect coding convention i don't know why not here, maybe i was tired, or maybe a copy paste i don't check well i don't remember ^^

Answer (score 1):

The UI is updated in the "[run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)".

The calls you're making tell iOS to display some views (alert, MUD...) and it'll do that on the next run through the loop.

What you need to do is wait for the user to respond to the alert before continuing. You do this by setting yourself as the UIAlert's delegate, then responding to the event:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 
    ...
}
```

There are also libraries available that allow you to pass a block to the alert view, thus simplifying the whole thing. (https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks, for example)

P.S. I see that you're new to Stack Overflow - please tick my answer if you're happy that it has responded to your question...

Comment: I use AliSoftware's classes but your answer is very well explain and i assume the libraries you propose also do the job, so thanks you very much. Sad i can't accept both answer.

Comment: I try but apparently i need 15 reputation point to vote up something.